# Extractor expression JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm looking for a way to get the value of a post processing and play on other requests without having to extract that value again,
My question is, is it possible to do this?
I'm already desperate.

The value I need to pass is the one in the image

[image]

I need to put in this requisition
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several post processors

1. For Regular Expression Extractor/XPath Extractor or CSS/JQuery Extractor: Reference Name is the variable saved e.g. a and then you can use it as ${a}
2. For JSR223 PostProcessor you can add vars.put("a", value); and then use it as ${a}
3. If you need global variable use property by adding: `props.put("a", value);` and get it later with: `${__P(a)}`

In your case add your variable to Body Data: `info_s"="${txtinfoInforma}"` ...

Comment: My problem is. That this resquisition is at the end, and the post processing, only serves the next correct request?

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: My problem is that I need to set this value in a request in the jmeter that is in the last place and the "" works only if I call the next request and I want to set this value to the last request, another question, if I can leave this Value that I draw globally.

it got better?

Comment: globally you can add it in property by using: `props.put("a", value);` and get it later with `${__P(a)}`